# Show comments for specific mappings in .vimrc

Tags: vim, keymapping

I know that I can use `:nmap, :vmap, :imap` commands to display all the mapping for those 3 modes. However, I would like to display comments that I have for a single mapping.

So suppose I have the following entry in my `vimrc`:

```
" Execute current line in bash 
nmap <F9> :exec '!'.getline('.')<CR>
```

This could also look like this:

```
nmap <F9> :exec '!'.getline('.')<CR> " Execute current line in bash
```

I would like to have a command that for this mapping that would look something like this:

```
<F9>      Execute current line in bash
```

As this probably can only be done using custom function, where do I start? How do I parse `.vimrc` to strip only key mappings and their corresponding comments (I have only done some very basic Vim scripts)?

Do I understand correctly from `:help map-comments` that I should avoid inline comments in `.vimrc`?

Comment: map cannot have "inline comment" as you mentioned helpdoc item.  also mappings could be created by plugins, in that case, you cannot find them in your vimrc file.

Comment: @Kent That's another interesting question - how to get mapping created by plugins.

Answer (score 3):

It's very hard to "embed" comments into a mapping without affecting its functionality. And this would only help with our own mappings, not the ones from plugins.

Rather, I'd suggest to learn from (well-written) plugins, which provide `:help` targets for their (default) key mappings. So, to document your mapping(s), create a help file `~/.vim/doc/mymappings.txt` with:

```
                                 *<F9>*
<F9>      Execute current line in bash
```

After `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`, you will be able to look up the comments via `:h <F9>`. By using the help file, you can use syntax highlighting, longer multi-line comments, and even examples, so I think that'a better and more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't have much use for such a feature for two reasons: the first one, is that I always have a vim session with a note taking buffer that contains all the tips/commands not yet in my muscle memory. Secondly, you can list all the maps using `:map`, and it's always a great exercise for your brain in learning vim to literally read vim commands.

That being said…

> *As this probably can only be done using custom function, where do I start?*

…well I guess you could imagine using a function with a prototype such as:

```
AddMap(op, key, cmd, comment)
```

used like:

```
call AddMap("nmap", "<F9>", ":exec '!'.getline('.')<CR>", "Execute current line in shell")
```

which implementation would add `key` and `comment` to an array, so that you could list the array to get your own mappings declared. Using a function like `ListMap()`.

```
let map_list = []

function! AddMap(op, key, cmd, comment)
  " add to map list
  insert(map_list, [op, key, comment])

  " execute map assign
  exec op.' '.key.' '.cmd
endfunction

function! ListMap()
  for it in map_list
    echo it[0] . '\t' . it[1] . '\t' . it[2]
  endfor
endfunction
```

Of course, one could elaborate on the `ListMap()` function implementation to generate a more "proper" help file that you could open in a buffer. But that's an idea of how you could do an implementation for a feature close to what you're looking for.

N.B.: this snippet is mostly *an idea* of how I'd tackle this problem, and it's a one shot write that I did not actually try.

> *How do I parse .vimrc to strip only key mappings and their corresponding comments (I have only done some very basic Vim scripts)?*

I don't think that would be a good solution, I think the better way to achieve your goal is my suggestion. Simpler and more explicit, though it won't show off *all* mappings. But you don't have all your mappings in your `.vimrc`.

> *Do I understand correctly from :help map-comments that I should avoid inline comments in .vimrc?*

To be more precise you *shall* not use inline comments after maps, because they will be interpreted part of the mapping.

> *how to get mapping created by plugins?*

Besides, using `:map`, you just don't. You look at the sources/documenation of your plugins and find out about them. There's no such thing as a reverse lookup from runtime to declaration point.